# Symlinking files with specific extension into another folder in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, exec

I currently have a number of drives mounted under "/media/"  I want to recursively scan all the drives mounted looking for files with a specific extension "*.foo".  Once found I want to symlink these files into a directory elsewhere.  One requirement is that I keep the basename of the file the same when creating the symlink.  I wasn’t able to come up with a an easy solution using "find -exec" on my own.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find /media/ -name *.foo | xargs ln -s -t DIRECTORYYOUWANTLINKSIN